# How to automatically expand empty packages in Eclipse with hierarchical presentation?

Tags: eclipse, ide

I have been often working on projects with huge namespaces on Eclipse.
Since I think that hierarchical package presention seems more visually helpful, I have the issue of selecting every package until the core classes, for example:

```
-br
-br.com
-br.com.company
-br.com.company.server.core
-br.com.company.server.core.web.common
-br.com.company.server.core.web.common.Utils.java (yay!)
```

Is there a way to automatically and recursivelly expand empty packages when using hierarchical package presentation?

So, when I click

```
+br
```

It would expand to:

```
-br
  -com
    -company
      -server
        -core
          -web
            -common
              +Utils.java
```

Comment: You can use the "Project explorer" view instead. It shows the complete package paths instead of the hierarchical view.

Comment: @Boris are you using Flat package presentation? That might be the case. Project Explorer has the same visual behaviour as Package Explorer for me.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the hierarchical representation flattens multiple empty directories (e.g.: com.company.project) into one expandable and collapsible entry. The one trick I found that causes this to NOT be true (on OSX anyway) is that .DS_Store files will cause Eclipse to see the directory as "not empty". It then won't compress them into one entry. Removing these files (and any other hidden but present files in the directory) resolves this issue.

I can thus have com.company.project expandable with one click and all the packages appear hierarchically under it. It's a nice combination of the two views!

Comment: This does not exactly answer the question the way the OP asked it but +1 for mentioning hidden files. This was exactly the problem that I was having with a flattened view of empty packages when using hierarchical view!

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Project explorer" view and change the "Package Presentation" from "Flat" to "Hierarchical". You find this setting in the view's menu.

Comment: This doesn't automatically expand the empty nodes here :(...could anyone confirm this solution?

Comment: I think that OP knows where is the 'hierarchical' representation - he want to automatically expand all the path instead of clicking "+" on each level.

Comment: @IHawk What Eclipse version do you use? In Indigo it works for me in all source directories and jar files.

Comment: @Boris - does it automatically expand all the empty packages till the concrete class, as shown in the question?

Comment: @PiotrNowicki Yes. It adds all empty package to one larger package, i.e. in the example above if Utils.java is the only class it shows only -br.com.company.server.core.web.common